# Scala/Spark wait for one function to complete before output the results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, static-methods, rdd

I have the following utility function in scala:

```
object MyUtiltity {

  def processData(data1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String], data2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String],
    data3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]) = {

    function1(data1, data3)
    function2(data2, data3)
  }
  
  private def function1 {...}
  private def function2 {...}
}
```

And in my main job, I call:

```
  MyUtility.processData(data1, data2, data3)
  data3.saveAsTextFile("myOutput")
```

It seems that data3 was not going through function2. Is there a way to make sure that the function1 and function2 computations in processData are finished before I output data3.

---

I guess I could do:

```
object MyUtiltity {

  def processData(data1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String], data2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String],
    data3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]): org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]= {

    val data3_1 = function1(data1, data3)
    val data3_2 = function2(data2, data3_1)
    data3_2
  }

  private def function1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]{...}
  private def function2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]{...}
}
```

and do:

```
MyUtility.processData(data1, data2, data3).saveAsTextFile("myOutput")
```

---

But I don't know if it is a good idea to keep returning the entire RDD in functions ... Would there be a smart way to approach this?

Comment: Looks like `function2` returns a `future` with which you'd need to `map` or `flatMap` to output.

Comment: You code is quite cryptic. It looks like you functions do not produce new rdds but just perform a lot of effects witch is not good thing to do. Rdds are just pointers to the data you should not try to mutate them. The second way looks mutch better.

Comment: In your first example you just run some functions on rdd and then saved the same data (not transformed one). Possibly u didnt even run any spark job (except saving) if there was no actions (just transformation in your functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDDs are lazy distributed collections. Nothing actually gets materialized until you explicitly persist it to some perm store or collected it on the driver.

Therefore, the entire call to `MyUtility.processData(data1, data2, data3)` doesn't really execute anything. Not until you call `saveAsTextFile("myOutput")`.

So yes, your second approach is perfectly fine and returning RDDs through functions is practically free.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code it seems like you are trying to modify the contents of an RDD. In Spark RDD's are imutable, instead the transformations will return a new RDD, so you likely just need to thread through the return values. Hope that helps!